# How to properly use a helper module inside a project?

Tags: python

I have a big C/C++ project with tons of settings. In order to simplify the build process for the different variants and configurations I wrote Python scripts in the form of a module.

So at the project root I have this `helpers` folder. The only thing I need to setup my working environment is to set my `PYTHONPATH` variable to my Git root folder:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

This gives me access to my helper module, but I doubt this is the best option.

What would be a good alternative to it?

Comment: What's wrong with that?  Put it in one of your startup files, like `.bash_profile`.

Comment: I don't know I feel it is not a good idea to do it so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One alternative could be to organize your module as a command.

You could make a main script, say `main.py`, and make a link to it in your `bin`:

```
user@host:home/user/bin$ ln ~/my_module/main.py buildhelper
```

Then make `main.py` executable: change its permissions, and add `#!/usr/bin/env python` as its first line.

```
user@host:~/$ chmod 755 ~/my_module/main.py
```

Now you would probably need your script to parse the console arguments so as to call different features. Your `main.py` could look like:

```
import my_module
import sys

def setup(*args):
    pass

def build(*args):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) == 1:
        print("No function requested")

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'setup':
        setup(*argv[1:])

    elif sys.argv[1] == 'build':
        build(*argv[1:])

    else:
        print("Invalid function")
```

Then, you would call your module's functions through such commands:

```
user@host:/anywhere$ buildhelper setup
user@host:/anywhere$ buildhelper build
```

**Pros**

- Works from anywhere
- Can be reused for another project
- Clean

**Cons**

- Works from everywhere: might be overkill if the scripts are too project-specific
- Might require extra work to organize the module as a command